# UI and hardware Button

Tags: tkinter, raspberry-pi, gpio

I want to call a function from a Switch(test) wired to the Raspberry. With the code posted below the function(asdf) is running when I click the Button on the UI. I deleted all the other stuff to make it look clear.
But how can I call the (test) function when the GPIO get´s LOW?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from tkinter import *
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(20,GPIO.IN)  # If Button is not pressed, Signal is HIGH
fenster = Tk()
fenster.geometry("100x100")


def test():
    if(GPIO.input(20)==False): 
        print("a")

def asdf():
    print("asdf")

b3=Button(fenster,text ="Referenzfahrt", command=asdf)
b3.config()
b3.pack(side="top")


fenster.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it:

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(20, GPIO.RISING, callback=lambda x: test(), bouncetime=1000)
```

With this line it calls the function when I press the Button